# Which binding's performance is best with grid view

Tags: asp.net, grid

I heard lot of binding methods such as JSON method to bind data to grid. i want know which one is best to bind data to grid. is any other new technologies used to bind data.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind straight from you data source output. Let's say you have a query that returns a

```
List<MyDataModel> TheList;
```

then you simply write this:

```
MyGridView.DataSource = TheList;
MyGridView.DataBind();
```

And you're done.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on personal preference. I myself like binding from a [DataTable](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable).

Comment: i want to render grid fastly than normal speed is any other method pls tell me

Comment: I've always used this method, and never had any problems with speed!

Answer (score 0):

In WPF datagrid view and winforms datagrid view is best one to read,bind,set the data's .More detail you can visit dapfor. com